# Avoiding "columnDefinition" attribute in @Column annotation in hibernate

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, hibernate-mapping

Is there a way to avoid the columnDefinition attribute of @Column annotation in hibernate?
Suppose I have a column in a table in the DB which is defined as enum('US', 'IN', 'GB', 'DE'etc) i.e. enum of all country codes . I map this to a attribute 'country_code' in java class representing the table using hibernate annotations. But without defining the columnDefinition hibernate throws an Exception saying
org.hibernate.HibernateException: Wrong column type for country_code. Found enum, expected varchar.

Is there a way to avoid columnDefinition attribute in @Column annotation?
Eg:

```
private UserType userType;
@Column(name="user_type")
@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
public UserType getUserType() {
    return userType;
}

public void setUserType(UserType userType) {
    this.userType = userType;
}
```

When I run the app with this mapping it throws an Exception saying:

```
org.hibernate.HibernateException: Wrong column type in gobe_user_db.gobe_User for column user_type. Found: enum, expected: varchar(255)
```

However when I add the "columnDefinition="enum('abc', 'xyz')"  to the @Column attribute it works.

Comment: Please, post some code. Your question is not clear to me ...

Comment: The standard way to map to an enum in the database is with an enum in the Java code.  Are you trying to map to a String in the java code?

Comment: I have mapped to enum only. But without columnDefinition attribute in @Column annotation it throws an exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The code you specified has a missing definition, hope the this will resolve the issue.**

```
   public enum EmployeeStatus {FULL_TIME, PART_TIME, CONTRACT}

   public enum SalaryRate {JUNIOR, SENIOR, MANAGER, EXECUTIVE}

   @Entity public class Employee {
       public EmployeeStatus getStatus() {...}
       ...
       @Enumerated(STRING)
       public SalaryRate getPayScale() {...}
       ...
   }
```

Look [here](http://tomee.apache.org/examples-trunk/jpa-enumerated/) for examples

Comment: Hi, I know how to map String to enum. But the question is if the column in the mysql database has type "enum('abc', 'cde')" then columnDefinition attribute is manadatory in Column annotation. I want to know if there is a way to avoid "columnDefinition" attribute in Column annotation?

Comment: As far as i know, there is no way to do that because the values returned from the table must be set to a variable and that variable must contain a type. The type definitions not just int, string char etc, but also all other type like enum, Class etc do the same thing to the variable.. ie; telling the compile that the variable is an object of a specified type that follows a particular order which is define in its corresponding class, ie String Integer etc. Hope you understand.

Answer (score 0):

You have missed `@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)`, use it with `@Column`

Comment: Hi I have posted the code. I have mapped it to @Enumerated(EnumType.String). But it still throws an exception.